# How to put the current date in logback filename with yaml?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, yaml, logback, spring-logback

In springboot, I'm trying to put the current date in my log filename lke this : `2020-01-31-log.log`

I tried this :

```
logging:
  level:
    root: info
    com.inyt.inytcirculationportal: debug
  file:
    name: "logs/%d-log.log"
```

but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the date in the log file like this does not seem like a good idea to me, even if you were able to inject it somehow in your properties. 
What if your application runs several days or months? You would only get a file per day if you restart the application at midnight. If you haven't done so, I'd recommend looking at the Logback [RollingFileAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender), which will automatically archive your current log file and start a new one at the interval you configured.
With the date pattern you mentioned, your log folder could look like this:

- app.log <- currently active log
- app.2020-01-30.log <- yesterday's log
- app.2020-01-29.log <- you get the idea ;-)